# Angular: How to create custom links around text strings using a filter

Tags: angularjs, json, replace, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with a json feed about cars. Part of the text has [VIN:'vin_number_is_here']Car make model here[/VIN]. I am using this in an ng-repeat and would like to, unless there's a better way, use a filter to process the text and create a hyperlink to a custom function ending up with something like `<a ng-click="modalViewCar('vin_number_is_here')">Car make model here</a>`

I have the replacement of the [/VIN] done but am at a loss for how best to handle the opening "tag".**

Additionally when I have hardcoded a test string I have found that the link never works which I assume is something Angular is responsible for...

```
app.filter('linkToVIN', ['$sce', function($sce) {
return function(input) {
    input = input.replace("[/VIN]","</a>");
    **input = input.replace("[VIN='12345abcdef']","<a ng-click=\"modalViewCar('12345abcdef')\">");**
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
};
```

}]);

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-bind-html="car.details | filter:search | linkToVIN"></div>
</div>
```

The VIN link is in the body of text. Sometimes multiple times. So each ng-repeat has a {{car.details}} which may, about 1 in 3 times, have at least one string with the [VIN] structure. What I'd really like to do is hot link those as they appear within the text as so far I have found a few outlier cases where there are references to other [VIN] numbers. E.g.

> *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [VIN:'12345abcdef']consectetur[/VIN] adipiscing elit. Vivamus laoreet odio nisi, eget gravida nunc porta gravida. Pellentesque nec porta tortor. In neque mi,[VIN:'000hijk']pretium[/VIN] at mattis ut, consectetur eget felis. Etiam tortor lacus, varius quis augue sed, condimentum varius massa.*

Which I would like to convert to.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, < a ng-click="modalViewCar('12345abcdef')" >consectetur< /a > adipiscing elit. Vivamus laoreet odio nisi, eget gravida nunc porta gravida. Pellentesque nec porta tortor. In neque mi,< a ng-click="modalViewCar('000hijk')" >pretium< /a > at mattis ut, consectetur eget felis. Etiam tortor lacus, varius quis augue sed, condimentum varius massa.

Comment: Where does the data come from? It's probably easier to parse out the VIN and transform the data objects before assigning them to your scope

Comment: I would not use `$sce` for **ANY** data coming outside of your app.  You open yourself up to an XSS attack.  Instead you need to use `ngSanitize`.

Comment: Thank you I will look into that. (It's coming from a server in the same domain so it's considered safe.)

Answer (score 1):

#### solving the regexp

You can do this with one regexp using multiple matching groups to build your anchor tags:

```
data.replace(/\[VIN:'([\w\d-_]*)'\](.*?)\[\/VIN\]/gmi, '<a ng-click="vc.modalClick($1)">$2</a>')
```

test - https://regex101.com/r/tU5sG2/2

#### compiling the DOM

The next issue is that you need to compile the DOM correctly.  In order to do that, I recommend a directive

```
.directive('vinContainer', function($parse, $compile){
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
       regex = /\[VIN:'([\w\d-_]*)'\](.*?)\[\/VIN\]/gmi
       anchor = '<a href="#" ng-click="vc.modelClick(\'$1\')">$2</a>'

       data = $parse(attrs.ngModel)($scope)
       parsed = data.replace(regex, anchor)

       elem.html(parsed).show()
       $compile(elem.contents())($scope)
   }
}
```

#### usage

```
<div vin-container ng-model="vc.viewData"/>
```

codepen - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/VeebEO?editors=101

---

This solution assumes that you are tightly coupling your directive to your view controller because your compiled anchors know which method to call.  You could further break this down by:

- creating an isolate scope with a callback expression you declare on the DOM
- have the compiled links call the callback expression passing back the id as the payload

Doing it that way would be much more scalable.  Here is the codepen for that version as well - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/yeeXJj?editors=101

Comment: I'm a bit lost with this. How would I use it with an ng-repeat?

Comment: The vin container directive processes all the matching vin strings within the string value passed to the `ng-model`.  If you have multiple sets of strings to pass via a repeater, then you can  say something like `<div ng-repeat="car in cars" vin-container ng-model="car"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Say your `cars` array looks something like this

```
var cars = [{details: "[VIN='12345abcdef']something[/VIN]"}, {details: ...}, ...];
```

You can transform it to a usable object by mapping the array

```
$scope.cars = cars.map(function(car) {
    var parts = car.details.match(/^\[VIN='(.+?)'\](.+?)\[\/VIN\]$/);
    return {
        vin: parts[1],
        details: parts[2]
    };
});
```

and then in your template

```
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <a ng-click="modalViewCar(car.vin)" ng-bind-html="car.details"></a>
</div>
```

---

This makes the assumption that all your `car.details` entries match the regular expression.

Comment: This is really nice but will not work as (my fault) I should have specified, the string does not always exist in the details block of text.

Comment: @freeBSD so explain what should happen in those cases. It's probably best if you provide an example of the `cars` array and the various formats it may contain

Comment: @freeBSD don't put important information in comments. Edit your question